# Does 与 change the meaning of 用中文与我联系不是一个好主意?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, writing-critique, conjunction

I ended up writing such a sentence, with some help of Google Translate:

> 用中文与我联系不是一个好主意。

I tried to say:

> *Contacting me in Chinese is not a good idea*.

Since my Chinese is pretty basic, I was wondering if that 与 here is needed for this sentence to be grammatically correct? Or can I skip it altogether?

Comment: What's the English equivalent that you're going for?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: to confirm that 与我联系 is perfectly standard feed it to ichacha:    请与我联系    reach me
    与我联系    contact me
    电话跟我联络    contact me by telephone
    请尽与我联系    if you have any questions pl... etc

Comment: 与（跟）某人 联系 may be more common than 联系某人，however Chinese is well known to have more transitive verbs than English, i.p. (if 我 is placed after verb 联系) 与 in fact is not needed 与我联系＝联系我, ichacha: 联系我们    contact me; contact us contact us...   详细翻译>>
系我     
如需更多信息,请联系我们的客户支持    for more information，contact our customer service desk...   详细翻译>>
想获取更多信息，请联系我们的客户服务台    for more information，contact our customer service desk...

Comment: As several answers have pointed out, there are many alternative ways to say this, but simply skipping 与 in your sentence is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'与' in '与我' means 'with'.

It can't be omitted

[用中文][**与**我联系][不是一个好主意]

[using Chinese] [(to) contact **with** me] [is not a good idea]

English grammar:

> It is not a good idea to contact **with** me using Chinese

The sentence is grammatically correct. Nothing wrong with that.

You can replace the relative clause [用中文] with other context and the grammar is still correct.

For example:

[在午夜] [**与**我联系][不是一个好主意]

[At midnight] [ contact **with** me] [is not a good idea]

English grammar:

> It is not a good idea to contact **with** me at midnight

Note:

联络 is the better choice than 联系 for 'to contact' in this case because 联络 only means 'to contact' while '联系' could also mean 'to connect' as in 'connect and form a relationship'

Answer (score 2):

**与** means together or with.

用中文与我联系不是一个好主意 = use + Chinese + with + me + contact + not + good + idea

The *与* here is not necessary.

In fact, 用中文与我联系 can be better written as 用中文联系我 which means **contacting me in Chinese**.

In English you probably wouldn't write *contacting with me in Chinese* and it's the same here in Chinese.

---

Sidenote: the only reference I found to "用中文与我联系" online is from a Japanese guy [Dr Taku Fujiyama](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/resilience-research/people/fujiyama)

> 如果您对我的研究有兴趣， 欢迎您用中文与我联系。

Answer (score 1):

> 用中文与我联系不是一个好主意。

The sentence you wrote makes perfect sense to me. Actually, it is a right one. 与 can't be omitted in this case. That reminds me of a typical caption translation from an English movie or TV show.

There are some other variations which a native Chinese might put for this context:

1. 你最好不要使用中文和我联系，我中文不太好。
2. 联系我时，请用英文，我中文不好，谢谢！

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, 与 here is a word connecting the hidden subject "你"(you) and “我”(me). It cannot be omitted.
Also, it's quite common for any foreign language learner (e.g. a Chinese learning English, or a Canadian learning Chinese) to write a sentence that is grammatically correct, but not quite natural or native.
You can translate your sentence as the follows:
最好别用中文跟我联系。(You'd better not communicate with me in Chinese. )
However, you can use a milder expression if you'd like to ask them to contact you in other languages:
请用英文与我联系。(I'd like you to contact me in English. )
See? It's a better practice to ask them "to do" something, rather than "not to do" something.